# I have an existing C++ project I want to add a new header file to in Visual C++. I get countless errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files

I have an existing totally functional project I am trying to add functionality to as part of a course project. I'm having trouble even getting past step one (not a great sign).

I've added a new .h file and it is riddled with errors.

`.h` files already in the project:

```
divide.h
subexpression.h
etc. etc.
```

The TOTALLY FUNCTIONAL contents of `divide.h`:

```
class Divide: public SubExpression
{
public:
    Divide(Expression* left, Expression* right):
        SubExpression(left, right)
    {
    }
    double evaluate()
    {
    return left->evaluate() / right->evaluate();
    }
};
```

After right clicking project name > add > new item > "header file" and then naming it greater.h I typed the following code into the greater.h file:

```
class Greater: public SubExpression
{
public:
Greater(Expression* left, Expression* right):
    SubExpression(left, right)
    {
    }
    double evaluate()
    {
   return left->evaluate() > right->evaluate();
    }
};
```

This file gives me two errors (and if I try to type anything else it only adds to the error list. It is clearly not linked to the project in any way for whatever reason. The errors are as follows:

(on the SubExpression class): **not a class or struct name**

On the word "class": **PCH warning: cannot find a suitable header stop location.  An intellisense PCH file was not generated.**

This can't possibly be complicated, but I have searched for hours and I cannot figure out why this basic process is failing.

Why isn't greater.h able to reference the other project files in the same way the other files are?

The files are in the same directory right next to each other.

**EDIT**
I'm adding a screenshot so you can see what I'm referring to personally.
[image: Visual C++ header]

Comment: `#include "SubExpression.h"`?

Comment: the `divide.h` file doesn't need/use an include for it why should `greater.h`? And that does not fix it either. Just adds the error "expected a file name"

Comment: Is that *all* that is in `greater.h`? Do you have `#include` for where  `SubExpression` is declared? You are not showing us enough of the file (or if that is all of the file, that is the problem).

Comment: @crashmstr there, the greater.h file can be identical to `divide.h` (in the same directory) with the exception of Divide being replaced with Greater and I get the same original errors with follow on errors as a result.

Comment: @bolov So why is it that divide.h doesn't need any include statements but greater.h does?

Comment: No header technically **needs** an include statement. If the compiler has all definitions it needs when it reaches the header, it won't cause errors. To assure this, you simply include everything the header uses inside the header.

Comment: Also note that this is not C# (or any other language using packages, assemblies and what have you). Adding a header file to the project will make no difference at all unless you include it somewhere in the compilation path of a translation unit (usually *.c or *.cpp files).

Comment: The red underlines are from intellisense. I see this getting it wrong a few times a week. Did the compiler have errors on both files? If not then I expect @Excelcius has the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#include` is a mere text-replacement. It places the contents of the file at the position of the `#include` statement. Therefore, it can cause seemingly weird effects when including different interdependent headers from a cpp file.

C++ compilers always start compiling from a translation unit such as a cpp-file. Headers are only included on the go. Therefore, the header doesn't have to know about `SubExpression`, but the cpp file to be the first to include `greater.h` must know about `SubExpression` before reaching `Greater`.

#### Example (test.cpp):

```
#include "greater.h" // Fails - what is SubExpression?
#include "subexpression.h"
#include "divide.h" // Works, by now the compiler knows about SubExpression
```

As you see, the order of inclusion can cause headers which look the same to behave different.

In order to avoid such problems, it is important to make the headers self-sufficient. They should include everything which is necessary to compile them. In case of a parent class you definitely need the definition of SubExpression so there is no harm to put an `#include "subexpression.h"` at the top of all your classes deriving from `SubExpression`.

If you do this, the above example will cause new problems, because "subexpression.h" will be included thrice and will cause redefinition errors. Therefore you should also place include guards using `#ifdef` or `#pragma once` at the top of your header files.

The PCH-error may be caused because precompiled headers must be included as the first header in any cpp file using the precompiled output. If your precompiled header is called "common.h" for example, every cpp file using it, must have `#include "common.h"` as the first statement in the cpp file (ignoring comments).